# How do I remove the time from DateAdd within a formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula to spit out strings based on certain criteria. Most of the time the criteria requires adding a few days to a date. However, in one condition it requires adding 6 month. So I used

```
DateAdd('m', 6, {client_record_sales_off.close_date})
```

If it were a field by itself I could use date format to show only the date. However, as it's part of a larger formula I am unable to do that. Is there a way to remove the time stamp when it's with a larger formula?

```
if {@pullExistence} = "New" and {#5Count} = 1 then 
totext({{client_record_sales_off.close_date} + 3)
else if {@pullExistence} = "Existing" and 
IsNull({client_prior.assessment_date}) then (DateAdd('m', 6, 
{client_record_sales_off.close_date}) & " 6 Month Review")
else if {@pullExistence} = "New" and IsNull({client_prior.assessment_date}) 
then (totext({client_record_sales_off.close_date} + 14) & " 14 Day review")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this:

```
CDATE(DateAdd('m', 6, {client_record_sales_off.close_date}))
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!